# Unable to retrieve data into RecyclerView from the Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: json, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srypR.png)
When I open the Activity "PhyList" where data should be retrieved it opens blank and then goes back to MainActivity or the app crashes. When I check Logcat window I understand nothing except " No adapter attached skipping layout " and error on the line PhyList.kt:35 " which is this following line " val physics = phySnapshot.getValue(Physics::class.java) ".

**The Activity where the data has to be retrieved.**

```
package com.zeeshan.universitytelephony


class PhyList : AppCompatActivity() {


    private lateinit var dbref: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var phyRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var phyArrayList: ArrayList<Physics>
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phy_list)

        phyRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.phyList)
        phyRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        phyRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        phyArrayList = arrayListOf<Physics>()
        getPhyData()
    }

    private fun getPhyData() {
        dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Physics")
        dbref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                if (snapshot.exists()){

                    for (phySnapshot in snapshot.children){

                        val physics = phySnapshot.getValue(Physics::class.java)
                        phyArrayList.add(physics!!)
                    }
                    phyRecyclerView.adapter = PhyAdapter(phyArrayList)
                }

            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }


        })
    }
}
```

**Data Class**

```
data class Physics(var Name: String ?= null, var Designation: String ?= null, var Email: String ?= null, var Phone: String ?= null)
```

**Adapter Class**

```
class PhyAdapter(private val phyList : ArrayList<Physics>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PhyAdapter.PhyViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PhyViewHolder {

        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false)
        return PhyViewHolder(itemView)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PhyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val currentitem = phyList[position]

        holder.Name.text = currentitem.Name
        holder.Designation.text = currentitem.Designation
        holder.Email.text = currentitem.Email
        holder.Phone.text = currentitem.Phone
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return phyList.size

    }

    class PhyViewHolder(itemView : View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        val Name : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName)
        val Designation : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDesignation)
        val Email : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail)
        val Phone : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPhone)


    }
}
```

JSON FILE

```json
{
  "Physics" : [ null, {
    "Designation" : "Coordinator/Assistant Professor",
    "Email" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "Name" : "Dr. Khalid Sultan",
    "Phone" : 941903XXXX
  }, {
    "Designation" : "Assistant Professor",
    "Email" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "Name" : "Mr. Raja Nisar Ali",
    "Phone" : 979706XXXX
  }, {
    "Designation" : "Assistant Professor",
    "Email" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "Name" : "Dr. Suhail Ahmad",
    "Phone" : 871393XXXX
  }, {
    "Designation" : "Inspire Faculty",
    "Email" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "Name" : "Dr. Rubiya Samad",
    "Phone" : 962285XXXX
  }, {
    "Designation" : "Teaching Assistant",
    "Email" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "Name" : "Mr. Abdul Mohsin",
    "Phone" : 979792XXXX
  } ]
}
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I hope this is not real personal information. Are these people OK with you giving out their names and email addresses publicly?

Comment: No problem.. Just hoping to get this fixed ASAP.

Comment: Didn't get any solutions yet.. :(